# How to pack python dict to XDR

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xdr

I have python dict:

```
data = {
  'foo': 'bar',
  'hello': 'world'
}
```

How to can I pack this dict to XDR data format?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you want it packed. As `key` `value` pairs, you could use the following:

Python 2.x:

```py
    import xdrlib
    
    data = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
    p = xdrlib.Packer()
    
    for key, value in data.items():
        p.pack_string(key)
        p.pack_string(value)
    
    print p.get_buffer()
```

Python 3.x:

```py
    import xdrlib
    
    data = {'foo': 'bar', 'hello': 'world'}
    p = xdrlib.Packer()
    
    for key, value in data.items():
        p.pack_string(key.encode())
        p.pack_string(value.encode())
    
    print(p.get_buffer())
```

Which would display something like:

```
◦◦◦foo◦◦◦◦bar◦◦◦◦hello◦◦◦◦◦◦world◦◦◦
```